Passing a generic class to a generic method using reflection
Here's the context:
We have a base class called Body, and many other classes that are inherited from the base class Body.
public class Body{
 //...
}

public class A : Body {
 //...
}

public class B : Body {
 //...
}

// and so on

And there is a service that has a Generic method like this:
public class TheService : ITheService
{
    public void Receive<T>(BasicDeliverEventArgs e, bool autoAcknowledge = false) where T : Body
    {
         var body = e.Body.ToArray();
         var rawMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);  
         var message = MessageParser.ParseMessage<T>(rawMessage);
         HandleTheMessage(message);
    }
}

And here is the deal, for all the classes that are derived from the base class Body, we must call the Receive function, so we are doing this:
// Getting all types that are inherited from the Body in the solution
 var bodyTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(domainAssembly =>   domainAssembly.GetExportedTypes()).Where(type => typeof(Body).IsAssignableFrom(type)).ToArray();

// Get the Receive method
var theService = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ITheService>();
var receive = typeof(ITheService).GetMethod("Receive");

// And finally calling the Receive function for all types
 foreach (var bodyType in bodyTypes)
 {
         var method = receive.MakeGenericMethod(bodyType);
         method.Invoke(theService, new object[] { firstInput, secondOne });
 }

It works literally fine.
The problem here is :
If the derived classes are generic themselves, it'll be encountered this error: Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true
public class C<D> : Body {
 //...
}

public class D {
 //...
}

The foreach code block is ok with classes A and B but it will throw an exception with that error message when it reaches C.
ChatGPT's answer:
The issue you're encountering stems from the fact that the MakeGenericMethod method cannot handle generic types that have not been fully specified (i.e., generic types with unassigned type parameters).
It is saying I must filter out open generic types, but I need them, I must not filter them out.
Does anyone have any idea how to solve the problem?

You would need todo the same thing, create a C for every possible T. As there is no real constraint on T yet presumably not feasible. Is it sufficient to use an example type for the T in C because this is only for testing? Your  Receive method presumably doesn't now anything about the "Inner" T here anyways.

So what do you want to happen?  You have your generic type C.  Do you want to skip it, use a specific generic argument for C, or what?  You have an explanation for why your code doesn't work, you need to decide what you want to do before you can figure out how to do it.

@Servy
I just want to call Receive method for all types that are derived from Body, even those ones that are generics. I updated the question to make it more clearer.

@AmiNZamani And you were given an explanation for why that can't work.  You'll need to figure out what the generic arguments should be for every generic type.  If you don't know what they should be, we can't tell you.  You need to figure out what you want it to be.

You need to call MakeGenericType on the non-constructed generic type definition to make it a fully constructed generic type. Of course, you need to know yourself which type argument(s) will be suitable for that.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.makegenerictype?view=net-8.0

I don't really understand the scenario, that makes you want to invoke Receive for virtually all possible types. Usually in service communication situation you may get objects of unknown type at runtime, that are guaranteed to derive from some base class, for example Body. And in the very moment you get it, it has ONE single type, which you can query with GetType() and then can do that reflection invocation on that very type just in time.

Imagine you were trying to call it directly yourself, without reflection. What would T be in the statement myService.Receive<C<T>>(someArgs) Unless you can work that out, it's not possible. If you can work out what you want then you can add that generic constructed type C<SomeType> to your list.

What Library is MessageParser from and is ParseMessage part of it or is it an extension you wrote yourself?

Get Type of each class that derives the Body class and check if it is generic.
Where in class C T can be of any class it is imposible to make as you wish.
